# What does confy stand for in Missouri (USA) city directory?

Tags: united-states, directories, missouri, abbreviations

In city directories around 1906 to 1910 for Independency, Jackson, Missouri, what does the abbreviation "confy" stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one directory for 1906 where the listing of companies in the rear listed the same address for which the abbreviation confy was used under Confectionary.

> Ancestry.com. U.S. City Directories, 1821-1989 [database on-line]. Provo, UT, USA: Ancestry.com Operations, Inc., 2011.

See pages 934 and 938 of the images of [the directory](http://interactive.ancestry.com/2469/11527763/632970551) for Confectionary owned by Foster at 114 North Liberty Street.